# 2GP post-installation Lightning Tab - set ConnectedApp.oauthConfig.isAdminApproved to true and assign profiles

Tags: apex, metadata-api, connected-apps, namedcredentials, 2gp

For a 2GP, putting together a UI for System Administrators to manually navigate to after installation to automate post-installation configuration.

Here's the part I am working on...
[image]

1. Sets ConnectedApp.oauthConfig.isAdminApproved to true
2. Assigns Profiles they select to ConnectedApp.profileName array

This can via the Metadata API.

My questions:

1. Can I use the Metadata.Operations? Seems like this might be restricted to custom metadata types and layouts based on my read of [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_supported_types.htm).
2. If #1 is no, then is my only option to create a Named Credential to the Metadata API endpoint then make Http requests from Apex?
3. If #2 is yes, then can I programmatically create a Named Credential using ConnectApi.NamedCredential?